Who "made" Gauss?
I was looking at the math genealogy related to probabilities and there was pretty much a straight line going from Kolmogorov to Laplace.
Then I got to Markov's sequence which gets a bit messy:
Markov -> Chebychev -> Brashman -> Lobanewsky -> Bartels -> Pfaff <- Gauss
(note that Bartels was also Gauss' tutor, Bartels was also a friend of Gauss)
but I couldn't find any direct link between this cluster and the first one.
For example, some of Gauss' students such as Cantor or Riemann obviously on top of Gauss' works, but who actually influenced him in his work in probabilities?
One interesting fact was that Gauss was also a friend of Bessel who he had met through his astronomy circle. Bessel had issues securing a teaching position because of his lack of formal education but had been working with Bernoulli's works which would be an easy link between those 2 gigantic clusters of mathematicians. He had received a honorary PhD from Gauss in order to be eligible to work at Göttingen, where he has worked from 1804 to 1843.
At around the same time, in 1804, Legendre came up with his method of least squares and Gauss came up with this own version of it a few years later in 1809, which he claims that he has been using since 1795. An honorary PhD is obviously not something you give to anyone, so would it be possible that he has worked or took credit for some of Bessel's works as a price?
Wikipedia states that Gauss was in accordance to "mundus vult decipi" which translates to "The world wants to be deceived, so let it be deceived.", so is there a possibility that he took credit of other people's work?

Anything is possible, but there is evidence to support Gauss's claim, see Stigler:"Examination of the French arc data must, I feel, be taken as supportive of the view that Gauss treated these data with least squares in 1799, more than five years before Legendre
published on the subject." This was also long before Gauss's encounters with Bessel, and Bessel left no indication that he considered least squares before Legendre. Gauss has been known to develop ideas without publishing on many other occasions, as confirmed by his diaries.
